# Ionic map controller not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, ionic-framework

I have a 5 tab's app one of which contains a map.The map  loads only when browsed to directly in the url bar.Otherwise it seems the controller is not loaded as i determined by some console logs. as the app will be run on mobile devices the map page will never be loaded first so i need a fix for this. I thought the controllers would be called when a tab is clicked but that doesn't seem t be the case.

**Controller**

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  //console.log("Map controller");
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //console.log('placing map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

  $scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
  };

})
```

**View**

```
<ion-view view-title="Directions">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map" class="card" data-tap-disabled="true">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Tabs**

```
<ion-tab title="Directions" icon-off="ion-ios-location-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-location" href="#/tab/directions">
   <ion-nav-view name="tab-directions"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

**Router**

```
.state('tab.directions', {
    url: '/directions',
    views: {
        'tab-directions': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-directions.html',
            controller: 'MapCtrl'
         }
    }
})
```

please ask questions it there is more info i can give you.

Comment: show your tabs.html?

Comment: Please add ng-contoller to your <ion-content> like

     <ion-content ng-controller="MapCtrl">.Its is not a good approach.Just for debugging

Comment: @Muhsin But this is in the router state. i tried this and it behaves the same

Comment: check your netowrk whether controller is not loading or not?

Comment: @Muhsin the controller is loading but still not functioning

Comment: Idiot question/thought: are you running this on a web server?

Comment: @diegot its running on local ionic development server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I execute the function when the view is entered. 
I added google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' ); after $scope.map = map; because the map only loaded after refreshing the view.

This is my controller:

```
.controller('MapsController', function($scope, $ionicLoading){

$scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
      map: map,
      title: "My Location"
    });
  });

  $scope.map = map;
  google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );
 });
});
```